# How can I change the amount of blur/transparency in the iOS7 navigation/tool bars?

Tags: ios, ios7

Without sub-classing/re-implementing, is it possible to affect how much blur/transparency is applied to the bars?

It seems to me, in some cases the background scene just blows out the underlying image so much that it ends up looking "almost" opaque.

Comment: Without sub-classing/re-implementing? No, it isn't possible. What you get is what you get. I have the impression that they reduced the amount of transparency in iOS 7.1, in response to user complaints, giving the effect you describe where you can barely tell that it's transparent.

Comment: Fair enough! I couldn't see anything exposed or documented. Figured I'd ask here. Thanks

Comment: @jacobsd would you consider changing the background of the bars? Because I know that you're able to change the bar's background by calling [UINavigationBar appearance] and setting a custom background image through method setBackgroundImage. In this way you'd specify a custom UIImage with your preferred alpha value

Comment: Yeah I saw that option mentioned here on SO -- related to re-implementing the "blur" effect. Overkill for my app, unless I'm certain people want it "super pretty".